# How to download HLS (HTTP Live Streaming)?

Tags: download, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I tried download HLS streaming with VLC tool, run `ffmpeg -i https://my-url.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4` on CMD and used `Video downloadhelper` as an `add-on` on Firefox.

All not working. I got the same error `403 forbidden` when use `Video downloadhelper` and `ffmpeg` on CMD.

Someone can help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no way for us to figure out what's wrong with your particular stream.  My guess is that you need some authentication header or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how to run an FFmpeg command using VLC. But this is an FFmpeg command to ingest 30 seconds from a live HLS and output to MP4.

`ffmpeg -re -i http://example.com/live_playlist.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a copy -t 30 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /output.mp4`

I'm not sure if you're ingesting from a live stream or a VOD asset. You can remove the '-t 30' if it's a VOD asset and you want the whole duration.

Try adding '-re' to your FFmpeg command, too. That may be what's missing.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

> -re (input)
> Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab device, or live input stream (e.g. when reading from a file). Should not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams (where it can cause packet loss). By default ffmpeg attempts to read the input(s) as fast as possible. This option will slow down the reading of the input(s) to the native frame rate of the input(s). It is useful for real-time output (e.g. live streaming).

Comment: **Don't** use `-re`.  It's totally inappropriate for this use case.  You want to stream from the source as fast as it will go, which for a realtime stream will be in realtime at the rate of the encoder.

Comment: They didn't specify if the HLS stream they're trying to capture to MP4 was live or VOD. The FFmpeg documentation states -re should be used for live input streams so I wouldn't say it's totally inappropriate.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's live or not.  If you use `-re`, it will attempt to use the local clock to time the input, buffering as-needed.  With clock drift over time, this will not stay in-sync.  The stream should be read as fast as possible, which will then follow the source encoder.

Comment: @iangetz the docs are a bit difficult to read at times, but they state A) Mainly used to **simulate** [...] live input stream and B)  Should **not be used** with actual [...] live input streams (where it can cause packet loss).